# Flip the html webpage horizontally not text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to the web page development, trying to implement two menus, one is next to the other, looking like mirrors.

The point is I found the way to flip it horizontally using following css,

```
body {
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Html is,

```
<body>
   <h1>Vertical Menu</h1>
   <div class="vertical-menu">
   <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   <a href="#">Link 4</a>
   </div>
</body>
```

but text is also inverted. What I cannot do is invert the menu letting the text as it is.

Complete CSS file is,

```
.vertical-menu {
 width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
 background-color: #eee;
 color: black;
 display: block;
 padding: 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
}
```

Checked the solutions to the similar questions, but not helped me.

Comment: flip the text as well? so the whole box, and then the text gets an additional flip...

Comment: cause u select the whole body which should be transformed

Comment: In your `vertical-menu` div, add another div with another class, for instance `vertical-content.` If you flip the menu to 180deg, then you flip the content to -180deg. It will keep your content horizontal and your menu vertical (but I think it would be 90deg ... But I use your numbers)

Comment: @marcellothearcane i'm trying to do the same. But not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css :

```
body {
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.vertical-menu {
 width: 200px;
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.vertical-menu a {
 background-color: #eee;
 color: black;
 display: block;
 padding: 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
}
h1{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Minar Mnr.

Answer (score 2):

With a few changes in your html and css, i got the result you want

**See code snippet:**

```css
body > div:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

body > div:nth-child(2) h1,body > div:nth-child(2) span {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

body > div, body span {
  display:inline-block;
}
.vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Vertical Menu</h1>
    <div class="vertical-menu">
      <a href="#" class="active"><span>Home</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Link 4</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Vertical Menu</h1>
    <div class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="#" class="active"><span>Home</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a>
      <a href="#"><span>Link 4</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Chiller.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.reflected` class to the mirror menu with the `text-align` property

```
.reflected{
  text-align:right;
}
```

```css
.vertical-menu {
 width: 200px;
}

.reflected{
  text-align:right;
}

.holder{
  float:left;
  padding:2px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
 background-color: #eee;
 color: black;
 display: block;
 padding: 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="holder">
   <h1>Vertical Menu</h1>
   <div class="vertical-menu">
   <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   <a href="#">Link 4</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="holder">
   <h1>Vertical Menu</h1>
   <div class="vertical-menu reflected">
   <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   <a href="#">Link 4</a>
   </div>
   </div>
   
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Raj.